# SQL Server : use other thing instead of union when date fetch from same table and different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I use `union` to combine selected data from table. All data selected from the same table but in each `select`, the query select some different columns.

Table schema:

```
   EID     name      x1       x2       x3
--------|--------|--------|--------|--------
   int    string   float    float    float
```

Sample data:

Sampletbl

```
  EID   name    x1     x2     x3
------|------|------|------|------
  110   Tom     2      3      5
  110   John    4      3      6
  110   Sam     1      2      3
```

Query:

```
select 
    name, 'x1' as title, x1 as result
from
    Sampletbl
where 
    EID = 110

union

select 
    name, 'x2' as title, x2 as result
from 
    Sampletbl
where 
    EID = 110

union

select 
    name, 'x3' as title, x3 as result
from
    Sampletbl
where 
    EID = 110
```

Output results should look like this:

```
 name   title   result  
------|-------|------
 Tom     x1      2      
 Tom     x1      3      
 Tom     x1      5      
 John    x2      4      
 John    x2      4      
 John    x2      6      
 Sam     x3      1      
 Sam     x3      2      
 Sam     x3      3
```

Question: is the better way to fetch data without use `union` or `union all` ?

DBMS used is SQL Server 2008 R2 but I can upgrade to SQL Server 2014 or newer.

**Update**:

Original table has millions of rows. Each select read data from table.
Each row is unique and columns have data. (nullable=False)
I want the way to increase performance and I can't change structure of result select.

Comment: Define 'better'.  What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @iamdave the query is slow, because table have million of records and decrease select and read data each time.

Comment: (I'm assuming your expected output should have just one `x1` row for each `name`, and the same for `x2` and `x3`, rather than what you're currently showing, because that's what your query will currently produce)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES`

```
SELECT v.*
FROM T
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (name, 'x1',x1),
                    (name, 'x2',x2),
                    (name, 'x3',x3)
            ) 
            v (name, title,result )
order by title
```

**[Results]**:

```
|  name | title | result |
|-------|-------|--------|
|   Tom |    x1 |      2 |
| John  |    x1 |      4 |
|   Sam |    x1 |      1 |
|   Sam |    x2 |      2 |
| John  |    x2 |      3 |
|   Tom |    x2 |      3 |
|   Tom |    x3 |      5 |
| John  |    x3 |      6 |
|   Sam |    x3 |      3 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a772d/1)

Answer (score 2):

It's called [`UNPIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017):

```
declare @t table (EID int, name varchar(13), x1 float, x2 float, x3 float)
insert into @t(EID,name,x1,x2,x3) values
(110,'Tom ',2,3,5),
(110,'John',4,3,6),
(110,'Sam ',1,2,3)

select
    *
from
    @t
    unpivot (
        result for title in (x1,x2,x3)) u
```

Result:

```
EID         name          result                 title
----------- ------------- ---------------------- -----
110         Tom           2                      x1
110         Tom           3                      x2
110         Tom           5                      x3
110         John          4                      x1
110         John          3                      x2
110         John          6                      x3
110         Sam           1                      x1
110         Sam           2                      x2
110         Sam           3                      x3
```

---

There is also a quicker, less intrusive, transformation to your current query if all of your output rows are going to be different (which from inspecting the current query, I'd expect to be true) - use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`. `UNION` is specified to *remove duplicates* and that can account for a significant proportion of the processing time if your output contains lots of rows.

Comment: table have 20 columns and all columns have data. Each record is unique  Is `union all` better than `cross apply` or `unpivot` ?

Comment: @AmirAbdollahi-  I'd only suggest `union all` if you're wanting to make minimal changes to your existing query. If `UNPIVOT` works correctly for you (ignoring performance for a moment), that's what I'd recommend because, *semantically*, that's what you're doing. So tell the server *what you want* and it'll then try it's best to do it efficiently. If `UNPIVOT` doesn't perform well, it's time to inspect execution plans and see if there are missing indexes, etc.